# RPi 4B with Ubuntu Server 20.04 fails to connect to Wi-Fi Sometimes

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, raspberrypi, netplan

I have Ubuntu Server 20.04 installed in RPi 4B. The problem is does connect to a network today but if i try to connect to the same network next day it fails. Why does this happen?

My .yaml is as below

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      access-points:
        <SSID>:
          password: <password>
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

Comment: Nighbours using the same channels as you are using? Check for inactive and free channels with e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer installed on your phone.

Comment: It is a modem and only RPi is connected to it

Comment: You're not alone in the world => Neighbours, unless you're living out in some kind of wilderness.

Comment: I do have Neighbours but i keep track on who connects to it xD and i haven't found anyone else connecting to it. Also i went through the kernel logs and i'm seeing this error `CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 status_code=16`

Comment: The fact that your neighbors use THEIR OWN Wifi, does affect the performance of YOUR WiFi - if they are using the same channels, or adjacent channels.

Comment: Wifi is similar to yelling in the manner that a loud enough yell from your neighbor distorts your yelling.

Comment: Ohh okay! My bad my bad I didn't understand that in the begining sorry

Comment: Also yes there are 3 networks running on same channel which is 6

Comment: Then simply try to move your settings as far away from channel 6 as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your neighbors are using the same channel(s) as you are using.
Check for inactive and free channels with e.g.
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer
... installed on your phone.

Wifi is similar to yelling in the manner that a loud enough yell from your neighbor distorts your yelling.

So simply try to move your (channel) setting as far away as possible from wifi-channels others are using, even swapping to e.g. 5GHz (from 2.4GHz) if there is more free space there.

Wifi (a radio signal) is also sensitive to distance between the communicating devices, also more so if there are (energy absorbing) obstacles in between.